How to test dynamic metric registration in custom prometheus exporter?
UPDATE: current source available here.
I'm currently working on a custom prometheus exporter for changedetection.io to expose both scraping and price metrics for all registered watches.
After having a working Proof-of-Concept, i'm trying to get the project maintainable and ready for release to the open source community (eg. adding tests & documentation and making it as feature complete as possible).
While writing those tests, i stumbled across a problem when trying to test the dynamic registration of new watches as they are created in the monitored changedetection.io instance. In order for the exporter to pick them up without a restart, i check the API for newly added watches on each collect run.
Here's the Collect function of the priceCollector:
func (c *priceCollector) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {
    // check for new watches before collecting metrics
    watches, err := c.ApiClient.getWatches()
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error while fetching watches: %v", err)
    } else {
        for id, watch := range watches {
            if _, ok := c.priceMetrics[id]; !ok {
                // create new metric and register it on the DefaultRegisterer
                c.priceMetrics[id] = newPriceMetric(prometheus.Labels{"title": watch.Title}, c.ApiClient, id)
                prometheus.MustRegister(c.priceMetrics[id])

                log.Infof("Picked up new watch %s, registered as metric %s", watch.Title, id)
            }
        }
    }

    // collect all registered metrics
    for _, metric := range c.priceMetrics {
        metric.Collect(ch)
    }
}

The newPriceMetric function simply creates a new priceMetric object consisting of a prometheus.Desc, an ApiClient (class providing access to changedetection.io's API) and a UUID:
func newPriceMetric(labels prometheus.Labels, apiClient *ApiClient, uuid string) priceMetric {
    return priceMetric{
        desc: prometheus.NewDesc(
            prometheus.BuildFQName(namespace, "watch", "price"),
            "Current price of an offer type watch",
            nil, labels,
        ),
        apiClient: apiClient,
        UUID:      uuid,
    }
}

Testing the default behavior works perfectly fine and passes all tests, but when i try to test the behavior of adding a new watch (while the exporter is running without restarting it), the test fails.

Notes: Both expectMetrics and expectMetricCount are wrapper-functions around prometheus' own testutil.CollectAndCompare and testutil.CollectAndCount. The helper CreateTestApiServer creates a wrapped httptest server which returns JSON payloads based on the passed map[string]*data.WatchItem structure.

func TestAutoregisterPriceCollector(t *testing.T) {
    watchDb := createCollectorTestDb()
    server := testutil.CreateTestApiServer(t, watchDb)
    defer server.Close()

    c, err := NewPriceCollector(server.URL(), "foo-bar-key")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    expectMetricCount(t, c, 2, "changedetectionio_watch_price")

    // now add a new watch and expect the collector to pick it up
    uuid, newItem := testutil.NewTestItem("Item 3", 300, "USD")
    watchDb[uuid] = newItem

    expectMetrics(t, c, "price_metrics_autoregister.prom", "changedetectionio_watch_price")
    expectMetricCount(t, c, 3, "changedetectionio_watch_price")
}

When running that test, the run fails with the following error:

collector_test.go:23: Unexpected metrics returned: gathering metrics failed: collected metric changedetectionio_watch_price label:{name:"title" value:"Item 3"} gauge:{value:300} with unregistered descriptor Desc{fqName: "changedetectionio_watch_price", help: "Current price of an offer type watch", constLabels: {title="Item 3"}, variableLabels: {}}

I currently assume that this error is related to the way testutil.CollectAnd* work internally. According to the function comments, they register the collector on a newly created pedantic Registry which may lead to it not picking up the lazily registered descriptor.
Any thoughts on that?

It's not clear from your question how CreateTestApiServer works. It appears that you create a server with a dataset of 2 entries, count the metrics and then create a second server with 2+1 entries and then attempt to redirect the collector to the new server. Would it not be easier for your test to add an entry to a map that's read by the server's handler? The first time through the map will contain x entries, then you add an entry to the map so that the second time through it contains x+1 entries.

Since this was bothering me anyways, i re-implemented the whole TestApiServer to no longer use file-based fixtures and rely on a passed map[string]*data.WatchItem structure. To my dismay, the result remains the same (see updated question) :( Also, i added a link to the source on GitHub

I'm unsure whether this answers your question but, here's an example
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log/slog"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/collectors"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/testutil"
)

var (
    endpoint = flag.String(
        "endpoint",
        "0.0.0.0:8080",
        "The endpoint of the HTTP server",
    )
)

type TestCollector struct {
    sync.RWMutex

    values []string
    foo    *prometheus.Desc
}

func NewTestCollector() *TestCollector {
    return &TestCollector{
        foo: prometheus.NewDesc(
            "foo",
            "foo",
            []string{
                "labels",
            },
            nil,
        ),
    }
}
func (c *TestCollector) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {
    c.RLock()
    defer c.RUnlock()

    for _, value := range c.values {
        ch <- prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(
            c.foo,
            prometheus.CounterValue,
            1,
            value,
        )
    }
}
func (c *TestCollector) Describe(ch chan<- *prometheus.Desc) {
    ch <- c.foo
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    c := NewTestCollector()

    registry := prometheus.NewRegistry()
    registry.MustRegister(c)

    go func() {
        for i := range 20 {
            value := fmt.Sprintf("value-%02d", i)
            slog.Info("Adding value", "value", value)
            c.Lock()
            c.values = append(c.values, value)
            c.Unlock()
            slog.Info("testutil",
                "count", testutil.CollectAndCount(c, "foo"))

            time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    http.Handle(
        "/metrics",
        promhttp.HandlerFor(
            registry, promhttp.HandlerOpts{}))
    slog.Error("unable to listen",
        "err", http.ListenAndServe(*endpoint, nil))
}

The metric foo has a growing (every 15 seconds) set (0..19) of labels (value-xx)
The CollectAndCount increases with each iteration:
logs:
2024/04/12 10:43:37 INFO Adding value value=value-00
2024/04/12 10:43:37 INFO testutil count=1
2024/04/12 10:43:52 INFO Adding value value=value-01
2024/04/12 10:43:52 INFO testutil count=2
2024/04/12 10:44:07 INFO Adding value value=value-02
2024/04/12 10:44:07 INFO testutil count=3
2024/04/12 10:44:22 INFO Adding value value=value-03
2024/04/12 10:44:22 INFO testutil count=4
2024/04/12 10:44:37 INFO Adding value value=value-04
2024/04/12 10:44:37 INFO testutil count=5
2024/04/12 10:44:52 INFO Adding value value=value-05

And:
curl --silent --get http://localhost:8080/metrics

# HELP foo foo
# TYPE foo counter
foo{labels="value-00"} 1
foo{labels="value-01"} 1
foo{labels="value-02"} 1
foo{labels="value-03"} 1
foo{labels="value-04"} 1
foo{labels="value-05"} 1


Refactoring the collector and getting rid of that weird priceMetric struct helped me not only resolve my problem with the tests, it also made my code way easier to understand and maintain! Thank you so much for your efforts, bounty will be awarded ASAP :)

I'm pleased to hear you got it working and that this helped. I learned about prometheus.testutil from your question. So, thanks for that! :-)
